# Optimize eigen recomposition (Matrix - Diagonal Matrix - Matrix) product C++ with BLAS and OpenMP

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, blas

I wrote a C++ code to solve a linear system `A.x = b` where `A` is a symmetric matrix by first diagonalizing the matrix `A = V.D.V^T` with LAPACK(E) (because I need the eigenvalues later) and then solving `x = A^-1.b = V^T.D^-1.V.b` where of course `V` is orthogonal.

Now I would like to optimize this last operation as much as possible, e.g. by using (C)BLAS routines and OpenMP.

Here is my naive implementation:

```
// Solve linear system A.X = B for X (V contains eigenvectors and D eigenvalues of A)
void solve(const double* V, const double* D, const double* B, double* X, const int& N)
{
    #ifdef _OPENMP
    #pragma omp parallel for
    #endif
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            for (int k=0; k<N; k++)
            {
                X[i] += B[j] * V[i+k*N] * V[j+k*N] / D[k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All arrays are C-style arrays, where `V` is of size `N^2`, `D` is of size `N`, `B` is of size `N` and `X` is of size `N` (and initialized with zeros).

For now, this naive implementation is very slow and is the bottleneck of the code. Any hints and help would be very appreciated !

Thanks

**EDIT**
Thanks to Jérôme Richard's answer and comment I further optimized his solution by calling BLAS and parallelizing the middle loop with OpenMP. On a 1000x1000 matrix, this solution is ~4 times faster as his proposition, which itself was 1000 times faster than my naive implementation.

I found the `#pragma omp parallel for simd` clause the be faster than other alternatives on two different machines with 4 and 20 cores respectively, for `N=1000` and `N=2000`.

```
void solve(const double* V, const double* D, const double* B, double* X, const int& N)
{

    double* sum = new double[N]{0.};

    cblas_dgemv(CblasColMajor,CblasTrans,N,N,1.,V,N,B,1,0.,sum,1);

    #pragma omp parallel for simd
    for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
    {
        sum[i] /= D[i];
    }

    cblas_dgemv(CblasColMajor,CblasNoTrans,N,N,1.,V,N,sum,1,0.,X,1);

    delete [] sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is currently highly **memory-bound**. Thus the resulting program will probably poorly scale (as long as compiler optimization are enabled). Indeed, on most common systems (eg. 1 socket non-NUMA processor) the RAM throughput is a **shared resource** between cores and also a scarce one. Moreover, the **memory access pattern is inefficient** and the algorithmic complexity of the code can be improved.

To speed up the computation, the j and k loops can be swapped so that `V` is read contiguously. Moreover, the division by `V[i+k*N]` and `D[k]` becomes constants in the most inner loop. The computation can then be **factorized** to be much faster since `B[j]` and `V[j+k*N]` is not dependent of `i` too. The resulting algorithm runs in **`O(n^2)` rather than `O(n^3)`** thanks to sum precomputations !

Finally, `omp simd` can be used to help compilers vectorizing the code, making it even faster!

Note that `_OPENMP` seems useless here since `#pragma` should ignored by compilers when OpenMP is disabled or not supported.

```cpp
// Solve linear system A.X = B for X (V contains eigenvectors and D eigenvalues of A)
void solve(const double* V, const double* D, const double* B, double* X, const int& N)
{
    std::vector<double> kSum(N);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int k=0; k<N; k++)
    {
        const double sum = 0.0;

        #pragma omp simd reduction(+:sum)
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            sum += B[j] * V[j+k*N];
        }

        kSum[k] = sum / D[k];
    }

    // Loop tiling can be used to speed up this section even more.
    // The idea is to swap i-based and j-based loops and work on thread-private copies
    // of X and finally sum the thread-private versions into a global X.
    // The resulting code should work on contiguous data and can even be vectorized.
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        double sum = X[i];

        for (int k=0; k<N; k++)
        {
            sum += kSum[k] * V[i+k*N];
        }

        X[i] = sum;
    }
}
```

The new code should be **several order of magnitude faster** than the original one (but still memory-bound). Note that results might be a bit different (as floating-point operations are not really associative), but I expect results to be be *more accurate*.

Comment: Indeed the loop factorization is giving a 1000x speedup, thank you ! I tried to perform the dot product `B[j] * V[j+k*N]` with BLAS and dividing by `D[k]` in the second loop, but it's slightly slower than your solution (for a 1000x1000 matrix), which seems odd to me. Maybe BLAS is going to be faster for even bigger matrices?

Also, how would you perform loop tiling with thread-private copies of X ?

EDIT: I removed `const` from `const double sum = 0.0;` since it did not compile: `error: 'const' qualified 'sum' without 'mutable' member may appear only in 'shared' or 'firstprivate' clauses`

Comment: Your final version looks good to me. However, note that the `#pragma parallel for` may be slower than a simple sequential loop (especially if N is not very big or if many cores are used). Vectorization can be used instead with `#pragma omp simd` (it should be fast enough).

Comment: Thank you! I updated my answer. In the end I found `#pragma omp parallel for simd` to be faster on different machines for medium-sized problems. I am not sure if it's because this clause is using both SIMD and parallel for ? Anyway, the problem is solved !

Comment: Exactly! `omp parallel for simd` is a factorized directive for `omp parallel` + `omp for` + `omp simd`.